# How to confirm an appointment

Tags: translation, word-usage

Someone asked, if I could meet on monday, how can I say that that day is ok?

> "Montag passt mir gut"

Is this informal? If so, what would be the formal way of saying that?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible answers that are formal. You can say your example as an answer:

> "Montag passt mir gut."

But you can also say, if the time has not yet been agreed:

> "Am Montag habe ich noch nichts vor. Wir können uns dann treffen. Um welche Uhrzeit?"

**Notice: Counter-question leaves an interested impression.**

Other possible answer would be:

> "Montag ist in Ordnung, wir können uns dann treffen."

> "Ja, wir können uns am Montag treffen."

Informal answer would be:

> "Montag ist ok"

(especially *short* answer were *informal*)

Comment: Not sure if "am Montag geht es mir (gut)" is a Swiss regionalism, but in Standard German this would mean something like "on monday I'm well" or "on monday I feel good".

Comment: Okay, I have change it ;)

Comment: Further informal and rather frequent versions are (in Germany): _Ja, Montag geht. / Ja, Montag geht bei mir. / Ja, Montag geht bei mir gut. / [Dienstag ist (bei mir) schlecht, aber] Montag wär' okay._ These sentences sound wrong, but they are popular in everyday language. However, using a formal language in an informal situation would sound more or less artificial (laboured) and strange to me.